# Processing: Code stops working without making any changes to it

Tags: processing, p5.js

So I've run into this issue a few times using Processing (p5.js mode), where seemingly out of the blue it doesn't want to compile.

The error reads: "SyntaxError: Expected ; but found *[name of my first variable]*"

[image: Screen Snip of error]

I can literally copy and paste the code into a new processing sketch and it runs. It's just annoying that I have to do that.

The last thing I did **this time** before it stopped working was rename the sketch. I can't remember if that's what happened with the other times I've had this issue, but I'm betting I would have been aware of that if so.

Any guidance on how to avoid this problem & correct it when it happens would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**edit** I should have mentioned that if I just double click the HTML file, the sketch runs fine. It's only when I try to run it in processing that I get the error.

**edit number two** on a different laptop with a new download of processing, the same error occurs in the IDE, while the sketch runs if I just double click the HTML file. I'm left to believe the issue starts and stops with the processing IDE.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Also make sure you're actually in P5.js mode.

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you actually close the tab and reopen it?

Comment: Same issue when I close and reopen it.

Yup I'm in P5.js mode. Not sure how to tell you how to recreate the issue. @KevinWorkman

Comment: @Anthony Did you read the [mcve] link? It tells you how to post an example that we can try ourselves.

Comment: @KevinWorkman "…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem" - the problem is that the code itself isn't the issue, considering I can copy paste it to another sketch and it works.    
"…Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem"  I've indicated all the relevant parts. Processing in P5.js mode, with an error that makes no sense.   
"…Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem" The code itself works so I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think `let` is valid in Processing.

Comment: @Anthony I'm not sure what to tell you then. Sounds like a configuration problem on your machine. Try uninstalling and reinstalling Processing, restarting your computer, all that stuff. Good luck.

Comment: @Anthony you should post the full code so it's easy for the rest of us to replicate/test/support. Could be a bug with the p5.js mode in Processing. Have you tried running a separate local web server instead of Processing's one to see if you get the same errors ?

Comment: So my laptop happened to kick the bucket yesterday. Today I downloaded processing on a new laptop, opened up the sketch in question, tried to run it and got the same error. Again, just double clicking the HTML file itself runs the sketch fine. The error only occurs in the processing IDE. @KevinWorkman thanks for your help regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/fathominfo/processing-p5js-mode/issues/18) (or, arguably, a feature) in the p5js mode of the Processing IDE. This mode apparently has an internal JavaScript parser which is stuck in ES5. For example, the following code works fine in any major browser:

```
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200,200);
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  x = 0;
  y = width/2;
}

function draw() {
  rect(x,y,10,10);
  x = (x+1)%width;
  y = (y+random(5))%height;
}
```

but you will run into problems when you try to work with it in the p5.js mode of the PDE. The problem disappears when `let` is replaced by `var`. Similar issues arise if you try to use code like `myArray.map(x => x*x)`

The p5.js mode seems like a small project with very little new code within the last year, so I wouldn't hold my breath on a fix. The [github description](http://brackets.io/) of the project in one place says:

> As with the rest of Processing, if you outgrow this setup, you should
>   use another IDE or development solution (like a full-featured
>   programmer's text editor and similar tools). We have no interest in
>   creating a JavaScript IDE. Also like the rest of Processing, we want
>   people to outgrow this setup.

Sounds like you have outgrown the set up. I recommend using something like [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) instead.

Comment: This makes complete sense. Finally I understand. Thank you